# Proper way to register HostedService in ASP.NET Core. AddHostedService vs AddSingleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-hosted-services

What is the proper way to register a custom hosted service in ASP.NET Core 2.1? For example, I have a custom hosted service derived from [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=aspnetcore-2.1) named `MyHostedService`. How should I register it?

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    //...
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyHostedService>();
}
```

or

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    //...
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
}
```

?

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/) we can see the first case, but [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) there is a second case.

Are these methods equal?

Comment: more recent docs recommended the seconds option

Comment: `Are they equal` the seconds one call the first one internally but as Transient, not singleton

Comment: It's more than which one is singleton and which isn't. Hosted services get special treatment from the runtime through their `StartAsync`, `StopAsync` methods. Using scoped/transient objects *is* possible by using scopes

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Update

> Somewhere between .Net Core 2.2 and 3.1 the behavior has changed, AddHostedService is now adding a Singleton instead of the previous Transient service.
> Credit - [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480324/proper-way-to-register-hostedservice-in-asp-net-core-addhostedservice-vs-addsin#comment110186397_51480627) by [LeonG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329143/leong)

```
public static class ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add an <see cref="IHostedService"/> registration for the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="THostedService">An <see cref="IHostedService"/> to register.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to register with.</param>
    /// <returns>The original <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where THostedService : class, IHostedService
    {
        services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, THostedService>());

        return services;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an <see cref="IHostedService"/> registration for the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="THostedService">An <see cref="IHostedService"/> to register.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to register with.</param>
    /// <param name="implementationFactory">A factory to create new instances of the service implementation.</param>
    /// <returns>The original <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services, Func<IServiceProvider, THostedService> implementationFactory)
        where THostedService : class, IHostedService
    {
        services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService>(implementationFactory));

        return services;
    }
}
```

Reference [ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs,44c8ac8d84044702)

---

### Original Answer

They are similar but not completely

`AddHostedService` is part of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`.

It belongs to  `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` in the [`ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs) class

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add an <see cref="IHostedService"/> registration for the given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="THostedService">An <see cref="IHostedService"/> to register.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to register with.</param>
        /// <returns>The original <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.</returns>
        public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
            where THostedService : class, IHostedService
            => services.AddTransient<IHostedService, THostedService>();
    }
}
```

Note it is using `Transient` life time scope and not `Singleton`

Internally the framework add all the hosted services to another service [*(`HostedServiceExecutor`)*](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/15008b0b7fcb54235a9de3ab844c066aaf42ea44/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostedServiceExecutor.cs#L18)

```
public HostedServiceExecutor(ILogger<HostedServiceExecutor> logger, 
    IEnumerable<IHostedService> services) //<<-- note services collection
{
    _logger = logger;
    _services = services;
}
```

at startup that is a singleton via the [WebHost Constructor](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/15008b0b7fcb54235a9de3ab844c066aaf42ea44/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L79).

```
_applicationServiceCollection.AddSingleton<HostedServiceExecutor>();
```

Comment: It means, that despite the fact that the service is registered as `scoped` inside `AddHostedService`, his lifetime will be as long, as application lifetime, right?

Comment: @Nkosi, how are transient services added to a singleton, shouldn't the Dependency injector throw in that case?

Comment: @DenisBabarykin yes that would be accurate.

Comment: @johnny5 no not necessarily. The transient will still get resolved. Just once by the singleton. :) [`Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options)

Comment: @Nkosi are they manually requesting the service, I thought the behavior changed between [.Net-Core 1 and .Net-Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45811225/1938988)

Comment: @johnny5 scoped is special. a singleton can still call a transient lifetime dependency. Technically the transient becomes a singleton itself as the instance will live in the singleton.

Comment: @Nkosi, Oh it's only for scoped, Thanks for that clarification I thought it was all lifetimes

Comment: @johnny5 scoped lifetime only lasts as long as the lifetime of the request. That is why it is treated differently.

Comment: Somewhere between .Net Core 2.2 and 3.1 the behavior has changed, AddHostedService is now adding a Singleton instead of the previous Transient service.

Comment: so if lifetime of a backgroundservice registered by AddHostedService() is effectively a singletion (which I can approve using net.core 5), what is the actual difference to a singleton service?

Answer (score 65):

**Update**

In the past, a HostedService was a long-lived transient, effectively acting as a singleton. Since .NET Core 3.1 [it's an actual Singleton](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs#L19).

---

Use `AddHostedService`

A hosted service is more than just a singleton service. The runtime "knows" about it, can tell it to start by calling `StartAsync` or stop by calling `StopAsync()` whenever eg the application pool is recycled. The runtime can wait for the hosted service to finish before the web application itself terminates.

As [the documentation explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) a scoped service *can* be consumed by creating a scope inside the hosted service's worker method. The same holds for transient services.

To do so, an IServicesProvider or an IServiceScopeFactory has to be injected in the hosted service's constructor and used to create the scope.

Borrowing from the docs, the service's constructor and worker method can look like this:

```
public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services, 
    ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
{
    Services = services;
    _logger = logger;
}


private void DoWork()
{
    using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var scopedProcessingService = 
            scope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

        scopedProcessingService.DoWork();
    }
}
```

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368634/how-should-i-inject-a-dbcontext-instance-into-an-ihostedservice) shows how to use a transient DbContext in a hosted service:

```
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            …
        }
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: Minor correction: a hosted service is not, in fact, a singleton service. You can call AddHostedService as many times as you want for some concrete class. The runtime will start up multiple instances of the service. This can be used with BackgroundService to set up a worker pool, for instance.

Comment: @kayjtea I wasn't implying it is, I was answering the question. But it looks like hosted services *are* singletons now

Comment: Does it work the same now? Will it be possible to do it through Factory and ActivatorUtilites.CreateInstance?

Comment: Using hosted services as a way to add an activated singleton is a very bad practice, please don't do this. Use https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/tree/main/src/Libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoActivation

Comment: What are you referring to? Hosted services do stuff in the background, they aren't just singletons instantiated at startup

Answer (score 19):

One huge difference is that `AddSingleton()` is lazy while `AddHostedService()` is eager.

A service added with `AddSingleton()` will be instantiated the first time it is injected into a class constructor. This is fine for most services, but if it really is a background service you want, you probably want it to start right away.

A service added with `AddHostedService()` will be instantiated immediately, even if no other class will ever want it injected into its constructor. This is typical for background services, that run all the time.

Also, it seems that you *cannot* inject a service added with `AddHostedService()` into another class.

Comment: Your last sentence was key for me.  I find it rather inconvenient that you can't DI a hosted service into another class!

Comment: @ErikWestwig You just have to wrap it in a scope.  Include `IServiceProvider services` to constructor and `services.CreateScope`

Comment: @DavidGraham, can you elaborate?  I'm experiencing the same frustration as Erik.  I want to create a master service that governs application lifecycle (hence must be derived from IHostedService and added with AddHostedService) but is also available to controllers (hence must be derived from IMasterService and added with AddSingleton).

Comment: @stephen How about adding the service as you would with `AddHostedService` but create an interface that you can get from the scope.  Your controllers can have access to the `IWorkerController`. You create that controller interface to do what you need but if you inject it into the worker and you controllers they all can use it.