# Correct way to start a BackgroundService in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, background-task

I have implemented a BackgroundService in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await DoSomethingAsync();
            await Task.Delay(10 * 1000);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I have registered it in my `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyBackgroundService>();
```

I am currently (reluctantly) starting it by calling (and not awaiting) the `StartAsync()` method from within the `Configure()` method:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<SummaryCache>().StartAsync(new CancellationToken());
```

What is the best practice method for starting the long running service?

Comment: Check out Steve Gordon's blog: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice

Comment: @junnas This unfortunately appears out of date (ASP.NET 2.0 preview before BackgroundService was made available) and it doesn't explain how to make a service start without explicitly invoking StartAsync()

Comment: Would hangfire be an option? https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: I implemented a background service using Steve Gordon's approach that runs on 2.2 preview 2 though?

Comment: By default, after registering `services.AddSingleton<MyBackgroundService>();`, it will start when application start, there is no need to call `StartAsync()` expecitly from your own code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to register HostedService in ASP.NET Core. AddHostedService vs AddSingleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480324/proper-way-to-register-hostedservice-in-asp-net-core-addhostedservice-vs-addsin)

Comment: Is there any way to stop the background service starting automatically and instead start on demand?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Explicitly calling StartAsync is not needed.

Calling

```
services.AddSingleton<MyBackgroundService>();
```

won't work since all service implementations are resolved via DI through IHostedService interface.
*edit:
e.g. 
    `svcProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>() -> IEnumerable<IHostedService>`*

You need to call either:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyBackgroundService>();
```

or

```
services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
```

edit:
*AddHostedService also registers an IHostedService: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2*

Comment: * to discover all background services to be run, the framework relies on DI and would call servcies.GetServcies<IHostedService>() which yields IEnumerable<IHostedServcie>. This resolves your service if you register via the Interface. .AddHostedService<T>() does exactly that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: what if for test purposes I want to create multiple instances of background services dynamically based on web API call? then can I call StartAsync?