# How to kill a thread in asp.net core

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing an application using asp.net core in which I need to create a new thread as I have an always running loop. At some point, I need to mill this thread. In asp.net, Thread.abort was the solution, but it is removed in asp.net core. What is the alternative solution for this?

Comment: *an always running loop* in a web context seems like a really bad idea. I'd imagine you are are spawning memory leaks all over your web server. *What is the alternative solution for this* don't do this at all...ever?! Either way it'd be [nice to see some code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). You should also use `Task` not `Thread` classes

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is almost never a solution. It can corrupt the run-time for the remaining threads. You should only ever call it when you're trying to crash out of an app completely.

Comment: The loop is to monitor a sensor, thats why I cannot run away from it

Comment: The idea of "an always running thread" is not consistent with "at some point, I need to kill this thread."

Comment: Threads, by definition, in any language, communicate by acting on shared variables. If you forcibly kill a thread, you risk leaving the shared variables in an inconsistent state. Forcibly killing one thread while allowing other threads to continue running is always bad practice. Threads should cooperate. If thread A needs thread B to die, then thread A should send a message _asking_ thread B to die, and thread B should be designed to handle the request by _cleanly_ shutting itself down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Do not create your own thread for something like this!

There is a built-in method for using long running tasks in asp.core. You should read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice).

You should create a class which derives from [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice). Using this class is the easiest way to create a background-service that implements `IHostedService`. You can then add this to your program by calling `services.AddHostedService<YourBackgroundService>()` in the `ConfigureServices` method.

**Note:** In the page I linked, they use `AddSingleton` instead of `AddHostedService`. In .net core 2.1 and above you should use `AddHostedService`, not `AddSingleton` (there are some exceptions but we're talking in general here). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481139/10883465) for why that is.

If you implement your background-service like this, the shutdown of the additional thread will be handled for you. In your implementation of `ExecuteAsync` you need to just check if you should stop executing with the provided `CancellationToken`. You should also use `asnyc` implementations where possible and provide the `CancellationToken` there as well so the thread can end gracefully. **You will never need to call `Thread.Abort` or even have access to the `Thread` itself; it's all done in the background for you.**

Since this is not a direct answer to the question you asked but more of a correction of what you're probably doing wrong to get into this situation in the first place, I first wanted to make this a comment. However it's just too long and there are too many things to mention that's why I made this into an answer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this via a flag that is set by the "killing" thread and checked periodically by the thread that needs to be killed. Thread.Abort() is not a reliable way to do it; even the MSDN says Calling this method **usually** terminates the thread.

Comment: In general, this is entirely correct. However OP is talking about asp.net core and there you really shouldn't create your own threads. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57326167/10883465) for what to do instead.

Comment: In .NET Core and .NET 5 and onwards Thread.Abort is not supported. They marked it as obsolete in .NET 5, because it doesn't abort the thread and should not be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/thread-abort-obsolete