# How to reference a hosted service in .Net Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Back in .net core 2, I had created a hosted service with a custom property like:

```
 public class MyService : BackgroundService 
{
public bool IsRunning {get;set;}
...
```

That I could setup in startup.cs like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService,HostedServices.MyService>();
...
```

And then I could reference it elsewhere in a razor page like:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHostedService _mySrv;
    public IndexModel(IHostedService mySrv) => _mySrv = mySrv;

    [BindProperty]
    public bool IsRunning { get; set; }

    public void OnGet() => IsRunning = ((HostedServices.MyService)_mySrv).IsRunning;
}
```

Now that I've upgraded to .net core 3, my startup has changed to:

```
services.AddHostedService<HostedServices.MyService>();
```

But my DI reference in IndexModel doesn't get me my MyService anymore, it gives me an object of type GenericWebHostService instead, that I can't figure out how to get my custom MyService from.  Changing 'IHostedService' to 'MyService' in IndexModel doesn't work either, i get a 'Unable to resolve service' error.

How do I get an instance of MyService back from dependency injection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In 2.2, the setup you had worked mostly by chance. Whenever you register multiple implementations against a service, the last-registered is the one that "wins". For example, take the following code:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, HostedService1>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, HostedService2>();

// ...

public IndexModel(IHostedServie hostedService) { }
```

The implementation of `IHostedService` that gets injected into `IndexModel` is `HostedService2`; the last registered. If `IndexModel` were to be updated to take an `IEnumerable<IHostedService>`, it would get *both* implementations, in order of registration:

```
public IndexModel(IEnumerable<IHostedService> hostedServices) { }
```

When I said "by chance", I meant that in your example, *only* `HostedServices.MyService` gets registered, so it's also the last-registered and therefore it "wins".

In 3.0, when using the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0), an implementation of `IHostedService`, `GenericWebHostService`, handles processing web requests. This gives you a problem, because the `GenericWebHostService` is registered *after* `HostedServices.MyService`. I hope it's clear by now that this is the reason why the `IHostedService` you request in `IndexModel` is not what you expected.

In terms of a solution, I suggest performing two registrations:

```
services.AddSingleton<HostedServices.MyService>();
services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<HostedServices.MyService>());
```

Then, update your `IndexModel` to require your specific implementation:

```
public IndexModel(HostedServices.MyService myService) { }
```

This allows you to target your specific implementation of `IHostedService`. It's registered twice, against two different service types, but only one instance gets created.

Comment: @KirkLarkin wait really? Where can I find proof for this because I don't understand what would call `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` on the service if you just add it as a singleton. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481139/10883465) seems to contradict your claims.

Comment: @Joelius So long as it's registered behind the interface `IHostedService`, it works fine. That's actually all `AddHostedService` does. I'll dig out a link to the source code to prove it...

Comment: @Joelius [Here you go](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/3.0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L48). The `Host` just requests `IEnumerable<IHostedService>` and calls `StartAsync` on them all. The answer you linked just says `AddSingleton` without specifying that interface doesn't work, and that's correct. I'm not saying any different. It's the second registration I've shown that ties them together.

Comment: Ohh that's something worth knowing. Is this mentioned in the docs? I feel like it's easy to assume that it might not do the same thing (although it's smart that it does).