# Multiple Instances of HostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I want to run multiple instances of the same hosted service.  I tried registering them twice:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
```

But ExecuteAsync is only called on one instance.

However if I have two different services:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyServiceA>();
services.AddHostedService<MyServiceB>();
```

ExecuteAsync is called on each one.

Is there anyway to run the same instance twice?  I in essence want to have two worker services doing the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is changed in .net core now and AddHostedService is now adds a Singleton instead of the Transient service.
So you can try this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyService>();
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480324/proper-way-to-register-hostedservice-in-asp-net-core-addhostedservice-vs-addsin/51481139) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38751)